# I am trying to extract a link from 'src' in an iframe element using Python-selenium but I end up with a no such element error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here's the HTML

```html
<div class="bg_tv col-md-12 online">
  <iframe width="100%" height="460" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dtKciwk_si4" scrolling="OFF" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
```

I tried:

```
browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe").get_attribute("src")
```

But I got:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe"}
```

and then I tried XPATH:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/iframe").get_attribute("src")
```

But got unable to locate element error as well. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *src* attribute of the `<iframe>` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bg_tv col-md-12 online']/iframe[@src]"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.bg_tv.col-md-12.online > iframe[src]"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 2):

Browser runners like selenium can be difficult because the runner may be executing the script before all elements of a page are loaded first. I would try adding a wait for the element first. As provided by the python-selenium documentation at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

This should get your element if it's loading in the browser context.